# general topology and elementary sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $$ be discrete space of two numbers $0,1$. Let $$ be infinite set, and let $$ be product space $^$. Let $=\prod_{\alpha \in A}_{\alpha}$ be elementary set in $$. if $ℎ$ is number of indices $\alpha$ such that $_{\alpha}\neq ,$ put $\mu()=2^{−ℎ}$. Now how to show if $_1,…,_ $ are pair wise disjoint elementary sets, then $\sum _{=1}^n(U_k)\leq 1$

Comment: the hint i got is -  write each $_k$ in form of $_\times _$, where $$ (independent of k) is complement of finite subset of $$, and $_$ is finite set; count up the number of points in $W_k$

Comment: You need the boring extra requirement that $V_\alpha \neq \emptyset$ for all $\alpha$.

Comment: yes, since $\prod_{\alpha \in A}^{-1} U_{\alpha}$ act as base for $X$, the requirement that $V_{\alpha}\neq \phi$ is obvious.

Comment: or we can simple add that since $U_k$ are disjoint and is finite for complement of finite subset of $A$, so $\sum \mu \leq 1$

Comment: is there any relation to Kolmogorov extension theorem  ? (because Elementary sets are the measure-theoretic analogue of cylinder sets in point set topology)

Comment: Not to prove this, but later you might apply it. This argument that’s asked for is to show we have a valid measure on a generating set.

Comment: by generating set you mean elementary set in X?

Comment: Yes, they are a generating set for the topology (not always for the Borel sets, as a $\sigma$-algebra).

Comment: here is how formulate the proof : consider the requirement that $V_{\alpha}\neq \phi$ for all $\alpha$.  allow the notation $U=\bigcup U_k$ where $U_k=\{ W_k\times K^{B_1}: K^{B_1}\in K^B$. $B_1$ is independent of $k$. now define $\mu(U_k)=\mu(W_k\times K^{B_1})$; $W_k$ is finite.  let choose $1\leq n_1\leq n_2.....$ such that $U_k\in U_{n_k}$ (because $u_n$ is increasing in $n$). now define a decreasing sq. $\{\tilde U_k\}_{k=1}^n$ as follow $$(\tilde U_1,...,\tilde U_n)=(K^{B_1},...K^{B_n},U_1...U_1,U_2..U_2,......)$$ then we have $U_k \in \tilde U_k$ for all $k$ and

Comment: continue : $ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \mu(U_k)=\sigma $ since $U_k \in \tilde U_k$ there exists $U'_k\in U_k$ such that $U_k=U'_k \times K^B$ for all $k$. using given ($X$ is product space $K^A$, let $V=\prod_{\alpha \in I} V_{\alpha}$ : $\mu (V)=2^{-h}$), there are sets $U_k\subset U'_k\subset \{0,1\}^A$ such that $\mu(U_k)\leq \sigma\times 2^{-h}\leq 1$ for all $k$

Comment: so, this explanation correct ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma am i correct in the explanation?

Comment: I couldn’t tell; it makes no sense to me.

Comment: this means i am wrong with solution. then how to solve it correctly, please.